# Calling super in a class inheriting a metaclass throws an error

Tags: python, python-2.x, super, metaclass

I am trying to use automatic registration of subclasses using a metaclass,
but the below code throws an error in **class Dep_A** on the line

`super(Dep_A,self).__init__().`

`*NameError: global name 'Dep_A' is not defined*`

Tried the commented line in MetaClass, but with the same error.
I know this works when not using a metaclass so how can I initialize the parent class's init method

```
registry = {}

def register(cls):
    print cls.__name__
    registry[cls.__name__] = cls()
    return cls


class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(mcs, clsname, bases, attrs):
        # newclass = super(MetaClass, mcs).__new__(mcs, clsname, bases, attrs)
        newclass = type.__new__(mcs,clsname, bases, attrs)
        register(newclass)
        return newclass


class Department(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass

    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = dict()


class Dep_A(Department):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dep_A,self).__init__()
        ...
```

Comment: So you are storing an *instance* of the class in the `registry` dictionary?

Comment: Yes @Martijn, or should I store the class to instantiate later.

Comment: BTW, you are, in 2018, writting the foundations for a new project using advanced Python features using Python 2, that will reach EOL in less than 2 years.

Comment: DCC software constraint, AutoDesk Maya is on python27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create an instance of the class *before the `class` statement has completed*. The class object has been created, but has not yet been assigned to a global name.

The order of events is:

- the `class Dep_A` statement is found, and the class body is executed to form the attributes (creating the `__init__` function).
- the metaclass `__new__` method is called with the classname, bases, and the class body namespace (`'Dep_A'`, `(Department,)` and `{'__init__': <function ...>, ...}` respectively).
- the metaclass creates the new class object
- The metaclass calls `registry()`, passing in the new class object
- `registry()` calls the class object
- The class `__init__` method is called

Normally, `Dep_A` is assigned when the metaclass `__new__` method returns the newly created object. *Until that point* there is no global name `Dep_A` assigned, so the `super(Dep_A, self).__init__()` call fails.

You could set the name from there first:

```
class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(mcs, clsname, bases, attrs):
        # newclass = super(MetaClass, mcs).__new__(mcs, clsname, bases, attrs)
        newclass = type.__new__(mcs,clsname, bases, attrs)
        globals()[clsname] = newclass
        register(newclass)
        return newclass
```

Alternatively, *don't try to create an instance in the registry*, store a class instead. You can always create a single instance *later on*.

The following implements a registry that transparently creates an instance later when you need one, and stores just that one instance created:

```
from collections import Mapping

class Registry(Mapping):
    def __init__(self):
        self._classes = {}
        self._instances = {}

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        if name not in self._instances:
            self._instances[name] = self._classes.pop(name)()
        return self._instances[name]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._classes.viewkeys() | self._instances.viewkeys())

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._classes) + len(self._instances)

    def register(self, cls):
        self._classes[cls.__name__] = cls

registry = Registry()

class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(mcs, clsname, bases, attrs):
        # newclass = super(MetaClass, mcs).__new__(mcs, clsname, bases, attrs)
        newclass = type.__new__(mcs,clsname, bases, attrs)
        registry.register(newclass)
        return newclass
```

Now classes are stored in a separate mapping and only when you then later look up the class from the registry mapping will an instance be created and cached:

```
>>> class Department(object):
...     __metaclass__ = MetaClass
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.tasks = dict()
...
>>> class Dep_A(Department):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super(Dep_A,self).__init__()
...
>>> registry.keys()
['Department', 'Dep_A']
>>> registry['Dep_A']
<__main__.Dep_A object at 0x110536ad0>
>>> vars(registry)
{'_instances': {'Dep_A': <__main__.Dep_A object at 0x110536ad0>}, '_classes': {'Department': <class '__main__.Department'>}}
```

Comment: The alternative approach is enlightening, thanks!. BTW I'm using this technique for dynamically choosing a subclass. Will this approach be wrong?

Comment: @river_bell: I don't know what your use case is, so I can't really tell, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your `register` function is trying to instantiate `Dep_A` before the global name is actually defined. (That is, it gets called while the body of the class statement is still being executed, before `Dep_A` is assigned the result of the call to the metaclass.)

You want to store the class *itself* instead:

```
def register(cls):
    registry[cls.__name__] = cls  # Not cls()
    return cls
```